# How to capture a literal in antlr4?

Tags: regex, syntax, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am looking to make a rule for a regex character class that is of the form:

```
 character_range
   : '[' literal '-' literal ']'
   ;
```

For example, with `[1-5]+` I could match the string "1234543" but not "129". However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how I would define a "literal" in antlr4. Normally I would do `[a-zA-Z]`, but then this is just ascii and won't include something such as `é`. So how would I do that?

Comment: Regex character classes are not limited to letters. You can use any range of unicode codepoints, including escaped characters such as `\u0634`. For example, `[\t-\r]` is a legal range, although I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't want to match an entire literal, because a literal can be more than one character. Instead you only need a single character for the match.

In the parser:

```
character_range: OPEN_BRACKET LETTER DASH LETTER CLOSE_BRACKET;
```

And in the lexer:

```
OPEN_BRACKET: '[';
CLOSE_BRACKET: ']';
LETTER: [\p{L}];
```

The character class used in the `LETTER` lexer rule is *Unicode Letters* as described in the [Unicode description](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements) file of ANTLR. Other possible character classes are listed in the [UAX #44 Annex](https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) of the Unicode Character DB. You may need others like *Numbers*, *Punctuation* or *Separators* for all possible regex character classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a range of unicode characters. Try something like this in your lexer rules:

```
fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment LETTER_UNICODE: [\u0080-\uFFFF];

UTF8CHAR: ( LETTER | LETTER_UNICODE );
```

Comment: Just a side note: just because the letter combination describes a Unicode character sequence, it doesn't mean this sequence is UTF8 encoded. Additionally, The ANSI encoding is part of Unicode, so it's actually subset of it and hence all characters starting at \0 are Unicode characters.

Comment: According to [this document](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/unicode.md), since v4.7, Antlr4 can handle the complete Unicode range, if you use the new interfaces, in languages which require them.